# Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, warnings

Can somebody explain to me why I got these warning in console, when I try to drag and how to solve it?

// Main Component

```js
  handleDragStart = data => event => {
    console.log("dataaa", data, "event ", event);
  };

  makeBoxes = () => {
    return this.state.boxes.map(box => (
      <Box
        key={box.id}
        box={box}
        draggable={true}
        onDragStart={this.handleDragStart}
      />
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="box-group">{this.makeBoxes()}</div>;
  }
```

// Box Component

```js
export default class Box extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { id, color, text } = this.props.box;
    return (
      <div
        className="boxElement"
        id={id}
        style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
        draggable={this.props.draggable}
        onDragStart={this.props.onDragStart({ id: id })}
      >
        <div>{text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I got this warning: 
Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `clientX` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-pike-o51yj

Comment: Please put the code in your question.

Answer (score 3):

In your BoxesGroup, I've edited the `handleDrag` function to look like this to solve it:

```
  handleDragStart = data => event => {
    event.persist();
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
    console.log("data", data, "event ", event);
  };
```

This is from React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html):

> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you
>   should call event.persist() on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

By default react has a pool of events and it keeps using them. (similar to a thread pool). To avoid react from putting the event back in the pool after you've used it, you can call `event.persist()`.

Comment: Thank you @Kinck, I know for this way, but in my opinion this should work without event.persist() cause this function handleDragStart is not asynchronous function.

Comment: React nullifies the properties of synthetic events right after executing an event handler. Since react has wrapped the dom events with its Synthetic Events. It's hard to guage the complete nature. Check this [https://deepscan.io/docs/rules/react-missing-event-persist]